# Does systemd still know about runlevels?

Tags: systemd, runlevel

Does systemd still have the concept of runlevels? For example is it pointless to use `telinit <number>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change runlevel with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498210/change-runlevel-with-systemd)

Comment: i don't know about the answers below, but in RHEL/Centos 7.6  `init 1` or `init 3` or `init 5` or `init 6` or `init 0` or `runlevel` still behave as they always have, and that's all I care about.  Much easier syntax then `systemctl blabla blabla.blabla`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[SystemD Run-Level Low-Down](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/)

Within the SystemD(aemon), runlevels are exposed as "Targets." The concept is still there, but the workflow to produce the desired result for your requirement is different.

The attached should clarify this issue.

**How do I change the current runlevel?**

```
$ systemctl isolate runlevelX.target
```

**How do I change the default runlevel for next-boot?**

```
# Create a symlink
$ ln -sf /usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

- `ln -sf TARGET DESTINATION`
- `-s` creates symbolic link
- `-f` removes the existing destination file

OR (as @centimane suggested) simply use the "blessed" `systemd` command:

```
systemctl set-default [target name].target
```

**How do I identify the current runlevel?**

```
$ systemctl list-units --type=target
```

Comment: Can I still use the init command to switch between runlevels?

Comment: If your systemd package is built with SysV compat support, it will include a telinit symlink to the systemd binary, which, when called as telinit, will map runlevels 0-6 to systemd targets - check telinit(8) for a list of those mappings.

Comment: To change the default target you should use `systemctl set-default [target name].target` rather than manually creating the link.

Comment: `systemctl list-units --type=target` does not identify the current runlevel, it lists all the active .target units though.

Answer (score 16):

No.  As the systemd people themselves wrote twice over, once in their `telinit` manual and once in their `runlevel` manual, runlevels are "obsolete".  You can forget about runlevels.

These things do not actually exist in systemd at all, outwith a few compatibility shims.

- There are some symbolic links for target names, but these targets are never actually used by systemd proper.

  - Rather, the bootstrap process employs a `default.target` (and thence one or both of a `graphical.target` and a `multi-user.target`), a `rescue.target`, or an `emergency.target`.  And the shutdown process involves a `shutdown.target`, a `reboot.target`, a `halt.target`, or a `poweroff.target`.  *No run-level targets are involved* in either bootstrap or shutdown.
  - The `telinit` command, which one might think uses the compatibility symbolic links to map its command-line arguments, does not do that either.  There's a hardwired table in the source code of the `telinit` program, and the numbers `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5` as arguments to the command are hardwired to map to `multi-user.target` and `graphical.target`.
  - `systemd-update-utmp` also has an internal hardwired table.
- There is no "init table" of runlevel stuff.  systemd is only compatible with van Smoorenburg `rc`, not with van Smoorenburg `init`.
- There is no "current run level" value maintained by systemd itself.  Rather, the almost wholly undocumented `systemd-update-utmp` command operates internally in terms of the activation states of `rescue.target`, `multi-user.target`, and `graphical.target`.
- `systemd-sysv-generator`, systemd's backwards compatibility service unit generator,  merges the `/etc/rc[234].d` directories into just the one `Wanted-By` relationship to `multi-user.target` in generated service units.  There is no actual reference to run levels in the generated service units.  (There used to be, years ago, but the systemd people found that this went wrong, because they weren't being referenced anywhere else.)

If one is a user of a system that builds systemd as did Arch Linux for the questioner at "[Why does `init 0` result in "Excess Arguments" on Arch install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389289/)", one does not even get the compatibility shims, and commands such as `init 0` result in the "native" systemd behaviour, which is to complain that the command has been incorrectly invoked.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering et al.. *[`runlevel`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/runlevel.html)*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al.. *[`telinit`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/telinit.html)*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering et al.. *[`bootup`](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html)*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- Lennart Poettering (2015-02-08). *[everywhere: remove configurability of sysv runlevel to target mapping](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/d5d8429a12c4b1ef0dcd226c0904f00f4fa4898a)*.  systemd.  github.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196197/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211927/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392612/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks very much. So, if I understood correctly:

For example:

```
ls -ll /usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel*.target
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel0.target -> poweroff.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel1.target -> rescue.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel2.target -> multi-user.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel3.target -> multi-user.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel4.target -> multi-user.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target -> graphical.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/runlevel6.target -> reboot.target
```

So as you can see, the concept of runlevels do exists, but it is quite obsolete due to the fact that the runlevel.target files are not actually “real” files but soft-links to the new, modern, better named files scheme which systemd likes to call them “targets”.

So, if you would like to do sth like `telinit 5` it would be like this: `systemctl isolate runlevel5.target`
which is identical with: `systemctl isolate graphical.target` (recommended in my opinion).

Just in case you are interested to know all the possible targets:

```
ls /usr/lib/systemd/system/*.target
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that you are understanding this correctly. I will be a late adopter of SystemD, as the procedural, step-step-step, INIT.D system is what I am most familiar with... I applaud that you are exploring SystemD. The best part of SystemD is its parallel multi-threading, which enables faster boot.

Multi-Threading boot can be accomplished with INIT.D, but requires strong BASH scripting.

Comment: BTW, `ls -ll` is equivalent to `ls -l`.  You might want to get into the habit of using `ls -ld`.

Comment: `telinit 0` / `telinit 6` still work. Since this helps with migration, and I think most distros still don't see a reason to drop the support yet. `isolate` clearly aspired to mimic how run-levels work, but there are various evil edge cases.  I highly recommend ignoring all instructions to `isolate runlevel5.target` or even `isolate graphical.target`. Example edge case: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6505

Answer (score 0):

systemd introduced *targets* as a counterpart for *runlevels* in sysV init system. sytemd developers made it almost compatible with most of the sysV scripts. Same happens for 
`telinit <runlevel>`. This is translated into systemd equivalent.

For example `telinit 0` powers off the machine. systemd has *poweroff.target* to do the same as *runlevel 0*. So `telinit 0` is translated by systemd to activate *poweroff.target*.

But some compatibility problems are there with sytemd and sysV init systems-> [https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/).