# Why is the localtime reset to the default timezone?

Tags: date, time, timezone

I use the following commands to set the timezone on our Amazon Linux (Centos) server:

```
ls -al /etc/localtime
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 25 dec  2012 /etc/localtime
sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam /etc/localtime
```

This backups the localtime file, so you can see if and when the time is set to the right timezone. Recently the time has been set back to the default. The bak file is still there, so I know I changed time in the past.

Is this because of a kernel update?

**Why doesn't time stay the same and is there a way to make sure it does?**

---

**Update**

This is the time of the updated localtime file:

```
$ ls -al /etc/localtime
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118 25 jun 19:05 /etc/localtime
```

Looking at /var/log/yum.log I see this:

```
Jun 25 19:05:27 Updated: glibc-common-2.17-55.143.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:30 Updated: glibc-2.17-55.143.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:31 Updated: libtiff-4.0.3-20.20.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:31 Updated: glibc-headers-2.17-55.143.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:31 Updated: subversion-libs-1.8.11-1.50.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:32 Updated: subversion-1.8.11-1.50.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:32 Updated: glibc-devel-2.17-55.143.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:32 Updated: libtiff-devel-4.0.3-20.20.amzn1.x86_64
Jun 25 19:05:32 Updated: python26-jmespath-0.7.1-1.9.amzn1.noarch
Jun 25 19:05:32 Updated: python27-jmespath-0.7.1-1.9.amzn1.noarch
Jun 25 19:05:33 Updated: glibc-2.17-55.143.amzn1.i686
```

So I suspect one of them to do this, one of the glibc updates I guess.

Comment: It definitely has nothing to do with the kernel.  It's more likely to be related to an upgrade of zoneinfo (or whatever it's named on your distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `ls -l /etc/localtime` to see at what time the change happened. Then look through logs such as `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and `/var/log/secure` for what might have started at around that time.

Note that now `systemd` has taken over `/etc/localtime` and there is a command

```
timedatectl set-timezone <zone>
```

that can change this file too. Also, there is a `systemd-timedated.service` which 
provides a [dbus service](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated) to change the timezone.
You can also look through the systemd logs:

```
sudo journalctl -l|grep timedate
```

You can find what scripts are run by the installation of an rpm by running

```
rpm -q --scripts glibc
```

for example for glibc. 
You can log the changes in a file by installing and starting `audit` and configuring a watch on the file with

```
sudo auditctl -w /etc/localtime -k mymarker
```

then looking through the logs with

```
sudo ausearch -k mymarker
```

Remove all rules with `sudo auditctl -D`. You will get info on any process that opens or changes the file, but if it is from a shell script that wont help much, as the command will just be `rm` or `ln`.

Perhaps if you use `timedatectl set-timezone` to change the timezone instead of linking it yourself it will do it in a way that further updates will accept and not change.

Comment: I've updated my question, and linked it to the yum log. I can set a cron script to check the time and renew the symlink, but is that the way to handle this?

Comment: @SPRBRN Until you find out the real problem, that's a good practical solution. I added some info on `rpm` and `audit` to my answer. Also, perhaps if you use `timedatectl set-timezone` to change the timezone it will do it in a way that further updates will accept and not change.

Comment: I'm aware of systemd, but don't think we're using it on our servers, and I don't know how to check it. (I can't believe we use it as this would have resulted in configuration changes.) However, that info is probably useful for others, so good to know.

Comment: Just found this answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196183/34756 and we're still using init.d!