# Does Yocto linux use SysVinit or systemd?

Tags: systemd, sysvinit, yocto

I'm struggling to understand boot process on Yocto linux (Dizzy) which I got as pre-built image.
It boots in xfce; pidof /sbin/init shows "1" which should mean that it's SysVinit. However, there is no /etc/inittab file and systemd process is started.

I just want to change default runlevel to 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yocto can create images utilizing either systemd or SysV init. In either case the program used as init will have pid 1.
As you are seeing a systemd process on your system you will have a configuration utilizing systemd. Systemd has no run levels perse.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at this answer and got confused http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196222/169552