# start a service using service not /etc/init.d

Tags: ubuntu, services

I have made modification to the file `/etc/init/hylafax`. When I start the `hylafax` service using `/etc/init.d/hylafax {start|stop}`, these modifications are executed. But when I start it using `service hylafax {start|stop}` , these modifications are not taken in considiration. What's the file to modifiy?

Comment: Which init system are you using?

Comment: How to know that? because the three system SysV init, upstart and systemd are present.

Comment: [It is actually quite a difficult problem](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196166/).  You have the advantage that _you know which one you chose_, even if that choice was to keep the installation default for your version of Ubuntu.  Which brings up the point that _your question needs to tell answerers the version of Ubuntu_ so that they can stand a chance at guessing what version of the hylafax package it is and thus look at the right one.  Even better, your question should _tell_ answerers what version of the hylafax package it is, _as well_.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 15.10 and hylafax 5.5.8 . My question is what files service command execute if it doesn't use /etc/init.d files