# How to determine a Linux distro is systemd or sysV init without installing or booting?

Tags: linux, boot, systemd, init, sysvinit

I noticed in somewhere that most of the Linux distro are based on Systemd instead of SysV init.

So I just want to know without installing and booting. Is there any possible way to find distro based on Systemd or SysV init ?

Comment: Read the homepage of the distribution.

Comment: Old but potentially useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18209/117549

Comment: An erroneous assumption underpinning this question is that distributions can only include one or the other, not both, nor other things entirely; and that no distribution exists where this is an installation, or post-installation, choice amongst several alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [distrowatch.com](https://distrowatch.com/) you can search for distributions using the init system as a criterion. You can even select "not systemd".

Comment: Thanks, I asked someone a similar question, this is a great way to get a list. Be aware that both "not systemd" and "systemd" are selecting Linux Mint as #1/#2 , for example. I think it's because the 17.x series is still in support and does not require systemd, based on [this comment](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=258868). So I guess you still have to double-check before you install.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the existence of the characteristic configuration files and administration tools of each init system.

If `/etc/inittab` does not exist, then the init system is definitely not SysVinit. If it exists but has only one non-comment line, and the comments are saying "this is only used for specifying the default runlevel, nothing else will have any effect", the init system might be `upstart`.

If `/etc/init/` is a directory, then the system configuration at least provides the option to use `upstart`.

If directories like `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, `/lib/systemd/system` and/or `/etc/systemd/system` exist, the system at least has the configuration files for `systemd`.

If `initctl list` as root produces a list of processes controlled by the init system, `upstart` is definitely in use.

If `systemctl status` displays a list of running system services (you don't even have to be root to run it!), `systemd` is definitely in use.

If `/etc/inittab` exists and neither `initctl list` nor `systemctl status` works, then it looks like SysVinit.

If `/etc/inittab` exists and it is having this line `inittab is no longer used when using systemd.` then it systemd only.

Comment: Now see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196252/5132 for the unwarranted assumptions that these involve.  (-:  Also note that the questioner explicitly asked about how to do this _without_ bootstrapping the system in question and running programs on it.

Comment: Oops. I plead -ENOCOFFEE.