# debian services not running

Tags: debian, boot

After an unexpected restart my debian machine is booting up to a terminal screen instead of gui.

I'm not sure what to do to diagnose the problem.. but I've noticed that all of the services in /etc/rc2.d/ (inittab says run level 2 ) are not running..

I look at cron for example : 
[image: running cron]

Someone please help me to understand why running S17cron doesn't work, but running the sym linked file directly works.

What am I missing? Does anyone know how or why my system is in this condition? how to fix?

Comment: I don't have anything to look at on my side but it's possible that it uses `$0` when it tries to use `systemctl` to start the service. The root of the problem is that it's trying to find a service called `s17cron` which it can't because the unit file is called just `cron` apparently.

Answer (score 12):

## Forget about `/etc/inittab` and run levels.

As the systemd doco says, in the systemd world the concept of run levels is "obsolete".  systemd itself works in terms of *targets*, not run levels.

Also obsolete is your `/etc/inittab` file.  The upgrade from Debian 7 to Debian 8 switches the init system from System 5 `init`+`rc` to systemd.  It leaves `/etc/inittab` lying around, because that file is not properly assigned as the property of a package in Debian 7.

What `/etc/inittab` says is entirely meaningless.  Not only does systemd totally ignore that file; but systemd does not have a concept of *current run level* in the first place.

## Forget about Systemv 5 `rc` scripts.

That's possibly a bit strong, but it's necessary to make the point that you have demonstrated several bad habits that you need to un-learn.  One, indeed, you had to un-learn *several version of Debian ago*.

- **Don't run scripts in `/etc/rc*.d/` directly.**  Firstly, you'll do it wrongly, as you are doing here, and things won't work.  Secondly, there's no guarantee that that symbolic link farm exists *even* on non-systemd systems.  One could be using [file-rc](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/file-rc) instead of [sysv-rc](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/sysv-rc), for example.
- **Don't run scripts in `/etc/init.d/` directly.**  On systemd operating systems there's no guarantee that those scripts even exist, let alone that they are what are specifying your service.  Even on Debian 7, there were systemd units supplanting System 5 `rc` scripts; and this is more so on Debian 8.  The correct commands to use are:

  - `systemctl` with its `status`, `start`, `stop`, `enable`, and `disable` subcommands
  - `service`
  - `update-rc.d` and `invoke-rc.d`, but *only if* you are a package maintainer script

The behaviour of the commands that you have observed is thus a complete red herring, and nothing to do with why your system is bootstrapping in the way that it is.

## Diagnose your problem properly with the tools available.

There are several programs that you should be running at this point.  These include:

- `systemctl get-default` to determine whether your system is even configured to boot to `graphical.target` in the first place.
- `systemctl list-units` to show what services and targets are running.  Your X display manager is a service.
- `systemctl status` to show *why* a failed service has failed.
- `journalctl -x -b` to look at the log since boot time.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196197/5132
- Stephen Wadeley (2014).  ["8. Managing Services with systemd"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html) *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 System Administrators' Guide*.  Red Hat.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemctl`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132