# How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?

Tags: systemd, init-script, init, sysvinit

I just switched to debian jessie, and most things run okay, including my graphical display manager `wdm`.

The thing is, I just don't understand how this works. Obviously my `/etc/init.d/wdm` script is called, because when I put an early `exit` in there, wdm is not started. But when I alternatively rename the  `/etc/rc3.d` directory (my default runlevel used to be 3), then wdm is still started.

I could not find out how systemd finds this script and I do not understand what it does to all the other init.d scripts.

- When and how does systemd run init.d scrips?
- In the long run, should I get rid of all init.d scripts?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

chaos' answer is what some documentation says.  But it's not what systemd actually does.  (It's not what van Smoorenburg `rc` did, either.  [The van Smoorenburg `rc`](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8290/1932) most definitely *did not* ignore LSB headers, which `insserv` used to calculate static orderings, for starters.)  The Freedesktop documentation, such as that "Incompatibilities" page, is in fact wrong, on these and other points.  (The `HOME` environment variable in fact *is* often set, for example.  This went wholly undocumented anywhere for a long time.  It's now documented in the manual, at least, but that Freedesktop WWW page still hasn't been corrected.)

The native service format for systemd is the *service unit*.  systemd's service management proper operates *solely* in terms of those, which it reads from one of nine directories where (system-wide) `.service` files can live.  `/etc/systemd/system`, `/run/systemd/system`, `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system`, and `/usr/lib/systemd/system` are four of those directories.

The compatibility with van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts is achieved with a conversion program, named `systemd-sysv-generator`.  This program is listed in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/` directory and is thus run automatically by systemd early in the bootstrap process at every boot, and again every time that systemd is instructed to re-load its configuration later on.

This program is a *generator*, a type of ancillary utility whose job is to create service unit files on the fly, in a tmpfs where three more of those nine directories (which are intended to be used only by generators) are located.  `systemd-sysv-generator` generates the service units that run the van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts from `/etc/init.d`, if it doesn't find a native systemd service unit by that name already existing in the other six locations.

systemd service management only knows about service units.  These automatically (re-)generated service units are written to invoke the van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts.  They have, amongst other things:

```
[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/wibble
[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/wibble start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/wibble stop
```

Received wisdom is that the van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts must have an LSB header, and are run in parallel without honouring the priorities imposed by the `/etc/rc?.d/` system.  This is incorrect on all points.

In fact, they don't need to have an LSB header, and if they do not `systemd-sysv-generator` can recognize the more limited old RedHat comment headers (`description:`, `pidfile:`, and so forth).  Moreover, in the absence of an LSB header it will fall back to the contents of the `/etc/rc?.d` symbolic link farms, reading the priorities encoded into the link names and constructing a before/after ordering from them, serializing the services.  Not only are LSB headers not a requirement, and not only do they themselves encode before/after orderings that serialize things to an extent, the fallback behaviour in their complete absence is actually significantly non-parallelized operation.

The reason that `/etc/rc3.d` didn't appear to matter is that you probably had that script enabled via another `/etc/rc?.d/` directory.  `systemd-sysv-generator` translates being listed in any of `/etc/rc2.d/`, `/etc/rc3.d/`, and `/etc/rc4.d/` into a native `Wanted-By` relationship to systemd's `multi-user.target`.  Run levels are "obsolete" in the systemd world, and you can forget about them.

## Further reading

- [*systemd-sysv-generator*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-sysv-generator.html). systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- ["Environment variables in spawned processes"](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes). *`systemd.exec`*.  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394191/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204075/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332797/5132

Comment: In Debian the system-generators directory doesn't live on /usr/lib, but /lib https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/systemd/filelist

Comment: This is a straight up amazing answer.  Well done sir.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you for this!  Dealing with a mix of Debian 8 and RH/CentOS 7 systems has made management of SysVInit vs Systemd service dependency management a bit of a headache but this explanation of what systemd is doing has helped my understanding greatly.

Comment: This generator does work.  I'd also mention, for followers, that if you have an older version of `systemd` and an /etc/init.d script isn't set to "boot on start" it will still work as expected but won't show up in the show-units lists: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518894/8337

Comment: This generator does work. I'd also mention, for followers, that if you have an older version of systemd and an /etc/init.d script that isn't set to "boot on start" it will still start/stop as expected using systemctl but won't show up in the show-units lists:https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517872/systemctl-list-all-possible-including-disabled-services/518894#518894 also NB that you basically "can't" control these service by running /etc/init.d/xx directly anymore or systemd gets...confused as to what is running and what isn't :|

Answer (score 21):

Systemd is [backward compatible](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Compatibility_Changes) with SysV init scripts. According to LSB 3.1, the init script must have informational [Comment Conventions](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html), defining when the script has to start/stop and what is required for the script to start/stop. This is an example:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: my-service
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop service my-service
# Description: my-service blah blah ...
### END INIT INFO
```

This is a commented section which is ignored by SysV. On the other hand, systemd reads that dependency information and runs those scripts depending on that.

But there is one point, where systemd and SysV differ in terms of init scripts. SysV executes the scripts in sequential order based on their number in the filename. Systemd doesn't. If dependencies are met, systemd runs the scripts immediately, without honoring the numbering of the script names. Some of them will most probably fail because of the ordering. There are a lots of other [incompatibilities](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/) that should be considered.

---

If there are init scripts and .service files for the same service, systemd will execute both, as soon as the dependencies are met (in case of the init script, those defined in the LSB header).

Comment: Okay, but I also have a whole bunch of .service files in /lib/systemd/system/. What does systemd actually execute? Whatever is specified in the service files (in dependency order), the init.d scripts or both?

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg I added that to the answer

Comment: As a sidenote, Debian has just announced to dump LSB compatibility: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.debian.devel.lsb/1103

Comment: systemd is anything BUT compatible with SysV scripts. Not only is that statement incorrect, but the referenced link makes it clear that it is only "mostly compatible" and the amount of effort needed to produce the same results is outrageously huge.

Comment: I found out the hard way that if the file in /etc/init.d is a symlink, the systemd generator "systemd-sysv-generator" that scans for legacy init.d scripts will skip it. My gerrit file in init.d was a symlink to /home/gerrit2/gerrit/bin/gerrit.sh, I fixed it with: cd /etc/init.d; sudo unlink gerrit; sudo cp /home/gerrit2/gerrit/bin/gerrit.sh gerrit