# Commands in init script refuse to run or actually do anything

Tags: mount, startup, init.d

Edit -- So it turns out that this line is the culprit
`. /lib/lsb/init-functions`

If I comment out that line then the commands are actually able to run. Why would this be? I'm able to source this file in my other init scripts with no issues.

So I have a script that I've place in `/etc/init.d` and run `update-rc.d` on. I can run this using `sudo /etc/init.d/usbstorage start`, and I get a message saying that is has started, but none of the commands have any effect. I can check this by putting simple commands like

`echo "here here maytee" > /home/pi/some_file.txt"`

in the script, and after running it that file does not exist. Part of the script is posted below for reference.

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          usbstorage
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: Automounts external storage if found.
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/bin

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    umount /dev/sda1 2> /dev/null || echo "sda1 not already mounted"
    mkdir /mnt/usbstorage 2> /dev/null || echo "/mnt/usbstorage already exists"
    mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usbstorage
    chown -R pi:pi /mnt/usbstorage
    echo "Started usbstorage"
}
do_stop () {
    umount /dev/sda1 || echo "sda1 not already mounted"
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        do_start
        ;;
  restart|reload|force-reload)
    do_stop || echo 1
    do_start
        ;;
  stop|status)
        # No-op
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: $0 start|stop" >&2
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

why do the commands refuse to run? It's almost like something is failing silently in the beginning .

--- Edit

So I ran the following:

```
sudo -i 
bash -x /etc/init.d/usbstorage start
```

and got this output

```
[ ok ] Starting usbstorage (via systemctl): usbstorage.service.
root@johns-box:~# bash -x /etc/init.d/usbstorage start
+ PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
+ . /lib/lsb/init-functions
+++ run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d
++ for hook in '$(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null)'
++ '[' -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks ']'
++ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks
++ for hook in '$(run-parts --lsbsysinit --list /lib/lsb/init-functions.d 2>/dev/null)'
++ '[' -r /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd ']'
++ . /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd
+++ _use_systemctl=0
+++ '[' -d /run/systemd/system ']'
+++ '[' -n '' ']'
+++ '[' 15898 -ne 1 ']'
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ case $(readlink -f "$0") in
++++ readlink -f /etc/init.d/usbstorage
+++ _use_systemctl=1
+++ prog=usbstorage
+++ service=usbstorage.service
++++ systemctl -p CanReload show usbstorage.service
+++ '[' CanReload=no = CanReload=no ']'
+++ '[' start = reload ']'
+++ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
+++ set +e
+++ set +u
+++ '[' xstart = xstart -o xstart = xstop -o xstart = xrestart -o xstart = xreload -o xstart = xforce-reload -o xstart = xstatus ']'
+++ systemctl_redirect /etc/init.d/usbstorage start
+++ local s
+++ local rc
+++ local prog=usbstorage
+++ local command=start
+++ case "$command" in
+++ s='Starting usbstorage (via systemctl)'
+++ service=usbstorage.service
++++ systemctl -p LoadState show usbstorage.service
+++ state=LoadState=loaded
+++ '[' LoadState=loaded = LoadState=masked ']'
+++ '[' start = status ']'
+++ log_daemon_msg 'Starting usbstorage (via systemctl)' usbstorage.service
+++ '[' -z 'Starting usbstorage (via systemctl)' ']'
+++ log_daemon_msg_pre 'Starting usbstorage (via systemctl)' usbstorage.service
+++ log_use_fancy_output
+++ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+++ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+++ '[' -t 1 ']'
+++ '[' xxterm-256color '!=' x ']'
+++ '[' xxterm-256color '!=' xdumb ']'
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/tput ']'
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/expr ']'
+++ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+++ '[' -z ']'
+++ FANCYTTY=1
+++ case "$FANCYTTY" in
+++ true
+++ echo -n '[....] '
[....] +++ '[' -z usbstorage.service ']'
+++ echo -n 'Starting usbstorage (via systemctl): usbstorage.service'
Starting usbstorage (via systemctl): usbstorage.service+++ log_daemon_msg_post 'Starting usbstorage (via systemctl)' usbstorage.service
+++ :
+++ /bin/systemctl start usbstorage.service
+++ rc=0
+++ '[' start = status ']'
+++ log_end_msg 0
+++ '[' -z 0 ']'
+++ local retval
+++ retval=0
+++ log_end_msg_pre 0
+++ log_use_fancy_output
+++ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+++ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+++ '[' -t 1 ']'
+++ '[' xxterm-256color '!=' x ']'
+++ '[' xxterm-256color '!=' xdumb ']'
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/tput ']'
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/expr ']'
+++ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+++ '[' -z 1 ']'
+++ true
+++ case "$FANCYTTY" in
+++ true
++++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+++ RED=''
++++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 2
+++ GREEN=''
++++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
+++ YELLOW=''
++++ /usr/bin/tput op
+++ NORMAL=''
+++ /usr/bin/tput civis
+++ /usr/bin/tput sc
+++ /usr/bin/tput hpa 0
+++ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+++ /bin/echo -ne '[ ok '
[ ok +++ /usr/bin/tput rc
+++ /usr/bin/tput cnorm
+++ log_use_fancy_output
+++ TPUT=/usr/bin/tput
+++ EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
+++ '[' -t 1 ']'
+++ '[' xxterm-256color '!=' x ']'
+++ '[' xxterm-256color '!=' xdumb ']'
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/tput ']'
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/expr ']'
+++ /usr/bin/tput hpa 60
+++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+++ '[' -z 1 ']'
+++ true
+++ case "$FANCYTTY" in
+++ true
++++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 1
+++ RED=''
++++ /usr/bin/tput setaf 3
+++ YELLOW=''
++++ /usr/bin/tput op
+++ NORMAL=''
+++ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+++ echo .
.
+++ log_end_msg_post 0
+++ :
+++ return 0
+++ return 0
+++ exit 0
```

Comment: Do you have other (simpler) scripts that run from `init.d`?  If your system uses `systemd` and is only backward compatible with `sysv` see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts).  Systemd is often quirky with backward compatibility.

Comment: yeah we have other scripts that run with `init.d` and run perfectly. There isn't any real difference between those scripts and this one except for the commands being run inside of the `do_start` function

Comment: Strange. It is like the execution stops after `. /lib/lsb/init-functions`. Do you get the help msg if you run the script without parameters?

Comment: I get the "Usage: /etc/init.d/usbstorage start|stop" message if I run the /etc/init.d/cam usbstorage with no other arugments. But I did confirm that by removing the sourcing of lsb/init-functions the commands in the script run but it looks ugly. I no longer get the nice logging of the service status

Comment: When you type this #! /bin/sh i think you want to do this #!/bin/sh this space does not exists, and more i think you want to use bash, because you're testing your scripts using bash. So the right way is #!/bin/bash , there are big differences between the shell interpreters!

Comment: All of our other shell scripts use #! /bin/sh and they work, but I tried your suggestion anyways and it had no effect.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR. Your start script does nothing because it is already "started",** says systemd. You need to *stop* it then you can *start* it.

As you can see in your shell trace output, when you run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/usbstorage start
```

on an OS using *systemd* as the preferred manager, which is your case, then the line

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

in your SysV-style script causes the shell code in

```
/lib/lsb/init-functions.d/40-systemd
```

to be run. It basically sees you need the systemd equivalent to your file, so prints

```
Starting usbstorage (via systemctl)
```

then runs

```
/bin/systemctl start usbstorage.service
```

and exits there. The rest of your script is never executed in this particular process.

However, each time someone calls `systemctl daemon-reload`, all the  `/etc/init.d/*` scripts are parsed and a small systemd unit file is created for each of them in `/run/systemd/generator/` (at boot) or `/run/systemd/generator.late/`.

The `### BEGIN INIT INFO` comment block of each script is converted into the equivalent systemd dependencies.
The unit file for your script, usbstorage.service, will include these lines

```
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/usbstorage start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/usbstorage stop
```

Hence that final `/bin/systemctl start usbstorage.service` issued just before the end of the execution of your script will simply run your script again with arg `start`, like you just did.  This time the environment holds `_SYSTEMCTL_SKIP_REDIRECT=true`, so the inclusion of `40-systemd` will not cause more recursion, and instead your script will execute as normal.

**So why does it not do anything when you run it?**

It all lies in the `RemainAfterExit=yes` line. This causes systemd to keep note of the fact that a *start* has been done, and so when you issue another *start* it will do nothing, because it is already started and "running".

You need to issue a *stop* first, then your *start* will actually fully run your script. You can check for the current state of your service eg:

```
$ sudo systemctl status usbstorage.service
* usbstorage.service - LSB: Automounts external storage if found.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/usbstorage)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-07-28 15:37:24 CEST; 26min ago
  Process: 7977 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/usbstorage start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 28 15:37:23 three usbstorage[7977]: <stdout/stderr of your script>
```

Notice how it says `active (exited)`.
You can look in the log for messages with

```
sudo journalctl -u usbstorage
```

Comment: This answer provides a very good overview of the SysV compatibility layer of systemd. The part about `RemainAfterExit` is inaccurate, though: systemd keeps note of the service status anyway. `RemainAfterExit=yes` only means that if the all processes of a service exit, its status remains _active_ (instead of changing into _inactive_ or _failed_). Which means a crashed daemon does not show up as _failed_, thus you can't _start_ (only _restart_) it, for example. But `RemainAfterExit=no` (the default) could not work in general, because many LSB init scripts don't leave behind running daemons.