# Debian fails to boot properly unless the Guest Additions CD is inserted

Tags: debian, boot, virtualbox

I have a Debian VM installed on a macOS 10.12 host. For some reason, whenever I eject the `VBOXADDITIONS` CD, I boot into emergency mode. It is only by remounting said CD and rebooting that I can boot normally. Is there a fix for this, or would I be better off just leaving it mounted?

There are references to the disk in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as shown:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20160917-14:22]/ jessie main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20160917-14:22]/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

There also are references to a `cdrom0` in `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=de666870-7693-4c4d-a11d-67158e0898a5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=4032a035-cc16-4483-a6ce-c2a5196be7b6 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,exec     0       0
```

Comment: What is in /etc/fstab and are there any references to the disc in /etc/apt/*

Comment: @ivanivan `/etc/fstab` doesn't exist and there are references to the disk in `sources.list`. I put its contents in the OP.

Comment: There must be an `/etc/fstab`

Comment: @Bahamut Ah, found it. I guess I didn't see it the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your /etc/fstab you are automatically mounting the CD when "mount -a" is issued during boot.

Change

```
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,exec     0       0
```

to

```
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660,user,exec,noauto     0       0
```

Comment: This is the right fix, but the explanation of its cause is wrong.  `mount -a` is _not_ run during bootstrap on systemd operating systems.  [`/etc/fstab` is converted to a series of mount units](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332797/5132), and the conversion process does not `enable` generated units made from records marked `noauto`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the sources list and put a # in front of the line

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 *Jessie* - Official amd64 xfce-CD Binary-1 20160917-14:22]/ jessie main

Save and exit.

It thinks that the CD is still in use as a Repository and needs to be present. The # , in Windows parlance rems it out and stops that.

Comment: See the new `sources.list` in the OP. It still boots me into emergency mode.