# systemd: Cannot disable generated unit file

Tags: systemd

How can I disable a unit generated by [`systemd-fstab-generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fstab-generator.html#) or [`systemd.generator`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html#)?

Here's my attempt:

```
$ systemctl is-enabled media-backup.automount
generated
$ echo $?
0
$ sudo systemctl disable media-backup.automount
$ echo $?
0
$ systemctl is-enabled media-backup.automount
generated
$ echo $?
0
```

As you can see from the exit status `0` the `.automount` unit is still enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332747/in-systemd-what-starts-units-generated-by-generator):

> Generated unit files are not automatically activated by systemd. There's nothing special about them as far as systemd is concerned. Each individual generator has to explicitly create symbolic links that connect a generated unit to a target, so that activating the target activates the generated unit via a dependency in the normal way.

Removing the symlink under `/run/systemd/generator/local-fs.target.wants` will disable the `.automount` until the next boot.

To stop the boot-time generation of the unit, add `noauto` to the `/etc/fstab` entry as [sebasth said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405585/143394).

Be aware that there is some magic required to[`stop an`.automount` unit without unmounting the filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405597/143394).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `noauto` [*option*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html#fstab) in fstab to disable systemd from automatically mounting the fstab entry.

Comment: Maybe. `systemd` will still manage `noauto` entries under circumstances which are poorly defined, and which the `systemd` maintainers refuse to fix. https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1741