# My system will not boot

Tags: linux, systemd, gentoo

I have a gentoo system, which uses systemd, a custom kernel, a custom initramfs, and a custom init script. This system was working. Now it does not. Clearly something must have changed, but I have no idea what.

When the init script launches the init system (`exec switch_root /mnt/root /var/lib/systemd/systemd`), I get the following error:

```
Welcome to Gentoo/Linux!

[!!!!!!] Failed to isolate default target, freezing.
```

What does this error mean? What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: This site(https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/) lists some systemd debug options.  Specifically, try adding "systemd.log_level=debug systemd.log_target=console systemd.journald.forward_to_console=1 console=tty1" to your kernel args.  It may help get more information to add to your question.

Comment: The questioner is asking what a specific message means, what causes systemd to emit it, and how to avoid that.  That could be answered in a mere 3 paragraphs.

Comment: @CodyCreager Is there some way I can pass those options directly to systemd when I switch_root? Adding arguments is easy, changing the kernel command line is not.

Comment: @JdeBP If you can provide that 3 paragraph answer, please do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In systemd jargon, *isolating* a unit is a slightly special form of *starting* or *activating* it, that can mostly (although I'll come back to this) be regarded as identical to activation.  systemd at bootstrap isolates one of three targets, according to whether the system is being started in emergency, rescue, or normal mode.  The first two are specified by `-b` and `-s` on the kernel command line that are passed along to the first process, and isolate `emergency.target` and `rescue.target` respectively.  Normal mode isolates the `default.target` unit, which is an *alias* (set with `systemctl set-default`) for some other concrete target such as `graphical.target` or `multi-user.target`.  A failure to isolate the first unit (from which everything else flows) is a fairly drastic error, and when that happens systemd emits a message and freezes.

It is unusual for `default.target` to not be isolatable, and it hints at either some serious misconfiguration (like the person who masked `sysinit.target`) or a highly unusual setup (such as a violation of one of the systemd premises, such as `/usr` and `/etc` being the same filesystem as, or at least mounted along with, `/`).  Diagnosing this further involves the aforementioned emergency and rescue modes.  Simply bootstrap into *those* modes instead of the normal mode, and then *manually* start the `default.target` unit, looking at what happens, what errors occur, and what is in the logs.  This is where the difference between isolation and activation is important.  One must *not* isolate `default.target`, as that shuts off the emergency/rescue mode login session as part of isolating the unit.  One must *start* it.

I seem to have a paragraph spare.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392612/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425540/5132

Comment: My root partition is encrypted. After unlocking, I have `/dev/mapper/main`. I mount that as root. However, systemd sees the entry for root in my fstab and fails to understand that I have already mounted it, causing boot timeouts. For a while, I fixed that by masking `dev-mapper-main.device`. However, recently I've been getting the failure to isolate error. So my choices are failure to isolate or boot timeout, both because systemd apparently doesn't realize I've already mounted root.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why my system wouldn't boot, I followed @CodyCreager's suggestion, mostly. I added `--log-level=debug` and `--log-target=console` to `exec switch_root ...`, which had the intended effect. I don't know how to achieve the same effect as adding `systemd.journald.forward_to_console=1` to the kernel arguments. But I got enough information without doing that.

As far as why my system isn't booting... that wouldn't help anyone. I am doing custom things in my initramfs, and custom things with my systemd setup, and systemd is not happy about it. Specifically, I am using an encrypted filesystem and I'm having trouble getting systemd to figure that out.

Comment: Regarding your encrypted filesystem, assuming it's the root filesystem, are you using a script in initramfs to unlock the LUKS container? That would create a /dev/disk/by-uuid/* device which you can reference in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: My initramfs/init script unlocks the container and mounts it as root. The unlocked device is `/dev/mapper/main`. I use that in my fstab. But systemd apparently can't figure out that its already mounted. So I masked `dev-mapper-main.device`, and that worked for a while. Now it doesn't. My solution is to have two fstabs, one in my root, and one in my initramfs.