# kernel add swap partition without it be list in /etc/fstab

Tags: debian, swap

I created a swap partition during installation, but I commented it out latter, and my computer has been reboot many times.

```
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
#UUID=71b04cbb-8779-4b0d-8664-9f2c402f5328 none  swap    sw              0       0
```

but I found the swap partition was still being used despite this:

```
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda3 partition 7.5G   0B   -2
```

I found the following entry in `/var/log/messages`:

```
debian kernel: [    5.665876] Adding 7812092k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:7812092k SSFS
```

I'm not sure what's going on and how to fix this. Can anyone help?

---

update

```
$ lsblk -o +PARTUUID
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT PARTUUID
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk            
├─sda1   8:1    0   190M  0 part /boot/efi  3838849b-e3fd-4b5f-81c0-422b61fa5b5e
├─sda2   8:2    0   286M  0 part /boot      2406c09a-459e-422b-86b9-24b993df1826
├─sda3   8:3    0   7.5G  0 part [SWAP]     4d1a1f8f-a4ae-4fad-b9ab-40c2e2f0c106
├─sda4   8:4    0  46.6G  0 part /          7552267d-9ca8-4b3a-bf42-e688cdc9ada1
├─sda5   8:5    0 111.8G  0 part            eb053a9b-bd97-44ab-b864-45655589f2c2
└─sda6   8:6    0 280.9G  0 part /home      6179cce6-66d5-42db-a288-5675910be9cb
```

```
$ systemctl list-units --type=swap
UNIT          LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                    
dev-sda3.swap loaded active active Swap Partition

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
```

```
 systemctl status dev-sda3.swap
● dev-sda3.swap - Swap Partition
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/generator.late/dev-sda3.swap; generated)
   Active: active since Thu 2021-04-01 16:56:20 CST; 16h ago
     What: /dev/sda3
     Docs: man:systemd-gpt-auto-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 536.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/dev-sda3.swap

Apr 01 16:56:20 debian systemd[1]: Activating swap Swap Partition...
Apr 01 16:56:20 debian systemd[1]: Activated swap Swap Partition.
```

to prevent the swap (/dev/sda3) from automount by systemd, use

```
sgdisk -A 3:set:63 /dev/sda
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `lsblk -o +PARTUUID`?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425540/108618).

Comment: `swapon`, really? Didn't you want to just list swaps? `cat /proc/swaps`.

Comment: @JiriB `swapon --show` (or `swapon` with no argument) displays the enabled swap, same as `cat /proc/swaps`; it doesn’t try to activate anything.

Comment: @StephenKitt interesting, anyway even if it maybe works like this than it's odd usage: `whatis -s 8 swapon` -> `swapon (8)           - enable/disable devices and files for paging and swapping`. It's like `rm` without argument would list files :D

Comment: What does `systemctl list-units --type=swap` show on your Debian?

Comment: @JiriB I agree it’s weird! But Roy’s use of it here wasn’t incorrect.

Comment: thanks KamilMaciorowski and Jiri B, I found the answer, systemd-gpt-auto-generator discover and activated my swap partition without it been list in /etc/fstab