# having 2 systemd directories

Tags: linux, systemd

right now I put my systemd scripts in `/etc/systemd/system`, but was wondering, is it possible to have two directories for systemd? One in its default location and another in lets say `/ebs_volume/systemd/system`. Reason for this is we have to trash our ec2 instances every x days and rebuild them and if I can keep application systemd scripts in the ebs volume, I wouldn't need to rebuild the systemd scripts then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't configure it.

You probably don't use `/usr/local/lib/systemd/systemd` for anything else, you could probably arrange a symlink or bind mount.

[How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts/233581#233581) lists four different directories systemd uses for system services.