# How to mount /run early enough?

Tags: systemd, raspbian

On a raspbian GNU/Linux 8 system, I get these errors during bootup:

```
ifplugd(eth0)[214]: Executing '/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action eth0 up'.
ifplugd(eth0)[214]: client: /sbin/ifup: failed to open lockfile /run/network/.ifstate.lock: No such file or directory
ifplugd(eth0)[214]: client: run-parts: /etc/ifplugd/action.d//ifupdown exited with return code 1
ifplugd(eth0)[214]: Program execution failed, return value is 1.
```

Later on, ifplugd repeats the action and succeeds. I suspect the initial failure is due to /run not being mounted. My questions are:

1. Is this normal behaviour or a bug/misconfiguration? ifplugd runs while systemd-fsck is still running, so it seems ifplugd is a bit early? Can I just ignore this problem?
2. Mounting /run appears to be a special case not handled by /etc/fstab because it needs to be present very early. So which part controls the mounting of /run? Is this done by systemd? If so, which part of systemd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `/run` is already mounted early enough.

Your diagnosis is faulty.

`/run` is mounted by the `systemd` program running as process #1.  It is one of the so-called "API filesystems" that systemd mounts before it even begins to bring up services and targets.  Indeed, systemd allows for `/run` to be mounted by the initrd stage of the bootstrap before process #1 executes the `systemd` program itself.  Whatever the  cause of your problem, it is not because of `/run` not being mounted.

Given that the problem is with a file that is in `/run/network/`, really your first thought rather should have been *Does the `/run/network/` directory yet exist at this point in the bootstrap?* leading to the question *What creates the `/run/network/` directory?* leading to the `networking` service that runs the `/etc/init.d/networking` script and whether it runs before or after the `ifplugd` service that runs the `/etc/init.d/ifplugd` script.  For the answer to which, see the very logs that you are looking at.  ☺

Yes, the `ifplugd` service is relying upon the `networking` service having been started first.  No, their van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts do not in fact encode this ordering.

## Further reading

- *[API FileSystems](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/)*.  Freedesktop.org.
- *[InitRd Interface](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/InitrdInterface/)*. Freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132