# Can systemctl list all enabled services, including legacy services?

Tags: systemd, startup, init-script, sysvinit, lsb

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795226/how-to-list-all-enabled-services-from-systemctl) asks: "How to list all enabled services from systemctl?"  Answers on that page include:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
```

At least as of systemd version 229 (on Ubuntu 16.04), `systemctl list-unit-files` will not include "LSB" services that are launched via legacy init scripts.

Therefore, the original question seems to remain unanswered:  Can systemd display a list of ALL the services (and other unit types) that it will try to start at boot, including legacy services?

Consider:

```
$ systemctl list-units | grep LSB | grep grub
  grub-common.service    loaded    active exited    LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB

$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep grub || echo 'nothing found'
nothing found

$ systemctl is-enabled grub-common
grub-common.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install is-enabled grub-common
enabled
```

`systemctl` knows about `grub-common`, and if you ask explicitly `systemctl` will tell you it is enabled.

So... is there a way to get systemd to display a list of ALL the services it will attempt to run at boot, including legacy scripts?

Comment: Does `systemctl list-units --type service --all` work for you?

Comment: Newer versions of systemd may include legacy services in `list-unit-files`.  For example, Debian 9 (Stretch) has systemd version 232.  However, I only have one LSB service on that system:  `raspi-config.service`.  It is `enabled`, but its state is `generated`.  It **is** listed when I run `systemctl list-unit-files --state=generated`.  But now we have a new wrinkle: a service that `is-enabled` but whose state is not `enabled`.  So it appears there is not a one-to-one mapping between being `enabled` and having a state of `enabled`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the command you want is:

```
systemctl list-units --type service --all
```

This from my test lists all service even those from legacy boot services.

Source:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-services

Comment: I believe `systemctl list-units --type service --all` will list all services, not all enabled services.  I just want enabled services, i.e., services that systemd will attempt to start at boot.

Comment: For me just running this works, and lists all "loaded" services, which AFAICT includes everything it attempted to load at boot time, ref: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units#adjusting-the-system-state-(runlevel)-with-targets maybe it's a version thing...

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type service --state enabled
```

Use `list-unit-files` to list installed unit files (not only the ones currently in memory). Some related sections from man page:

```
  list-units [PATTERN...]             List units currently in memory

  list-unit-files [PATTERN...]        List installed unit files
  
  is-enabled UNIT...                  Check whether unit files are enabled

-t --type=TYPE         List units of a particular type
   --state=STATE       List units with particular LOAD or SUB or ACTIVE state

-a --all               Show all properties/all units currently in memory,
                       including dead/empty ones. To list all units installed
                       on the system, use 'list-unit-files' instead.
```

On old versions of systemd [this wasn't true](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-May/042555.html):

> In really old systemd versions "systemctl list-unit-files" only showed native unit files. In newer versions we also display generated unit files, to make them more discoverable.

I tested each generated services with `is-enabled`. Some return `enabled`, some `disabled`, and some a third state "`generated`" (which all are). I'm not sure about those.

```
systemctl is-enabled $(systemctl list-unit-files --type service --state generated | awk '/.*\.service/ {print $1}' | tr '\n' ' ') |& grep "^\w*$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

#### Related links

- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal#getting-an-overview-of-the-system-state
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/209677

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's been so long since I asked the question that I may no longer have easy access to a system on which I can test your answer.  When I asked the question, I was (probably) running Ubuntu 16.04, but I am now running 20.04 and 21.04, and the `grub` example in my question no longer works as it did back on 16.04.