# systemctl list all possible (including disabled) services

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I have a "service" that originates from an /etc/init.d/XX script, and a systemd [wrapper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233468/8337) is generated for it.  It doesn't autostart in any runlevel, and when I run `systemctl --all` or `systemctl list-unit-files --all` it doesn't show up in any list.

My hunch is that because it has no dependencies, hasn't been started, it isn't "loaded" into systemd (so not enabled, not loaded) so systemd doesn't list it.

Is there a way to get a *full* list of all possible services, even those not yet started and that aren't auto-started?  Or do a `systemctl search` equivalent?

This related [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411494/can-systemctl-list-all-enabled-services-including-legacy-services) only asks for a list of services that will be attempted at boot time.

The `man` [page](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/systemctl.1.html) for `systemctl` under "--all" says

> To list all units installed on the system, use the list-unit-files command instead

but these disabled units do not show up in the output of `list-unit-files`.

Comment: How you tried `systemctl show XX`?

Comment: `systemctl show XX` works, but I'm looking for a way to list "all the possible options for XX" as it were...even those that don't auto start, I added to the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK I asked "the systemd guys" and they said in old versions it didn't list them all, despite the man page saying this:

```
   -a, --all
       When listing units, show all loaded units, regardless of their
       state, including inactive units. When showing unit/job/manager
       properties, show all properties regardless whether they are set or
       not.

       To list all units installed on the system, use the list-unit-files
       command instead.
```

Most of the functionality listed above didn't seem to actually happen with "my" systemd version `systemd 219` (CentOS 6).  But it seems fixed in newer versions of systemctl on Debian 9 which has version `systemd 232`, perhaps that's why.

You can still control them like normal (status, start, stop) with the older `systemd` version if the init.d script *does* specify runlevels but is absent from all `/etc/rc?.d` dirs (a la `chkconfig --del my_service` or its equivalent `systemctl disable my_service`, or if `chkconfig` was never run initially on it) then the `systemd-sysv-generator` with older versions of systemd it doesn't [show up in the lists][2] if you run `systemctl list-units --all` etc. even though it's working fine and still controllable.  Or if they're normal services but disabled they seem to also not show up in any lists, despite being still functional.

ref: 
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-May/042555.html

Answer (score 7):

List every loaded service that is running, active, or failed in the system:

```
# sudo systemctl list-units --type=service --all
```

List all Disabled services in the system:

```
# sudo systemctl list-unit-files --type=service --state=disabled
```

List all Enabled services in the system:

```
# sudo systemctl list-unit-files --type=service --state=enabled
```

List every loaded service that is active state in the system:

```
# sudo systemctl list-units --type=service --state=active
```

List every loaded service that is running state in the system:
**This is my favorite command**

```
# sudo systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running
```

List every loaded service that is failed state in the system:

```
# sudo systemctl list-units --type=service --state=failed
```

List every loaded service that is exited state in the system:

```
# sudo systemctl list-units --type=service --state=exited
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Updated with full explanations.

Comment: And would this work when the service is a `/etc/init.d` script with a systems wrapper, as described in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Are you running these commands as root? I believe that the list-unit-files command is exactly what you're looking for. It lists the unit files and not just the list of loaded services. I think you're likely looking at an issue with how your service is configured.

Maybe start by creating a dummy service and make sure it gets registered. Something that doesn't actually do anything. Then once that's working you can see how it differs from the service that isn't working. Or compare your service unit file with one of a simple service that is working.

Comment: There's a systemd SysV generator that translates init scripts to unit files, actually.

Comment: OK I did some tests, even using a dummy `systemd` service, and it appears that if "any" service is `disabled` (i.e. bound to no targets), then after a `systemctl daemon-reload` it no longer shows up in any lists...so it's not an issue exclusive to the `systemd-sysv-generator` methinks...

Answer (score 0):

A cool TUI for `systemctl`:

[joehillen/sysz: An fzf terminal UI for systemctl](https://github.com/joehillen/sysz)

A [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) terminal UI for systemctl

Installation:

```
wget -O ~/.bin/sysz https://github.com/joehillen/sysz/releases/latest/download/sysz
chmod +x ~/.bin/sysz
```

Usage: `sysz <other systemctl args as you wish>`