# How can I list services and timer units with systemctl which can be enabled after installing new unit files?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

## My situation

I installed a few new unit files under `$HOME/.local/share/systemd/user/`

```bash
ls -1 $HOME/.local/share/systemd/user/
some.service
some.timer
some_other.service
```

I ran the following command to have them loaded properly: `systemctl --user daemon-reload`

They show up in auto completion of `systemctl --user enable <tab> <tab>`. What I'm looking for is a way to later write a script with [gum](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum) to show me a list of those units which are currently not enabled to enable them.

## My question

Is there a better way than `ls -1 $HOME/.local/share/systemd/user/` to get the list I'm looking for?

`systemctl` knows about the units through auto completion, but I don't want to that deep for a seemingly rather simple question. I looked at [systemctl list all possible (including disabled) services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/517872/49853) and some parts of the Systemd documentation, but I wasn't able to find what I was looking for yet. It doesn't have to be perfect, the auto complete list also has some other entries which I could filter out. That won't be a problem for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, `systemctl --user list-unit-files` shows the list of all user services.

So you can run the following command in order to get the list of user services that are disabled:

```
systemctl --user --full --no-legend --no-pager list-unit-files --state=disabled
```

By the way, you can look at the [bash completion file](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/shell-completion/bash/systemctl.in)  of `systemctl`  to see how it gets the list of disabled services, which is very similar:

```
__systemctl() {
    local mode=$1; shift 1
    systemctl $mode --full --legend=no --no-pager --plain "$@" 2>/dev/null
}

[...]

__get_disabled_units() { __systemctl $1 list-unit-files "$2*" \
                              | while read -r a b c  ; do [[ $b == "disabled" ]] && echo " $a"; done; }
```

You can also find this file on your local machine. In my case it's located at `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl`, but I'm not sure if it's the standard path for all disros.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering what kind of magic would be at play. Now I see that `echo " $a"` outputs the first column (= unit file name). Ok, now I don't have to feel ashamed for using `awk {print $1}` to get what I want. The path to bash completers should be pretty much standardized in distributions which integrate Systemd. For Ubuntu it is https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/systemd/filelist the same, for other distributions the quickest way I know of would be https://pkgs.org/search/?q=systemd&on=files and looking at the file list. :-)

Answer (score 5):

aviro's answer motivated me to spend a bit more time on this. This is what I came up with now:

```bash
SYSTEMD_COLORS=no systemctl list-unit-files \
    --full \
    --no-legend \
    --no-pager \
    --state=disabled \
    --type=service,timer \
    --user \
| sort \
| awk '!/^(obex|rygel|wireplumber)(@)?\.(service|timer)/ {print $1}'
```

- You don't need `SYSTEMD_COLORS=no`, systemctl itself should detect that its output is sent to a pipe, but I leave it here for readers who will be further experimenting with the code.
- I included `--type=service,timer` because I had at least one `.socket` unit in my list.
- `obex|rygel|wireplumber` is a list of units I don't want to have in the selection. If you want to use an allow list instead of a deny list, you need to remove `!` at the beginning.

As I wrote in my question, I further process this with gum, so awk is followed by `| gum choose` in my script. It makes sense when you look at the [project's site](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum).