# systemd doesn't recognize init.d status

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I have created systemd script - /etc/systemd/system/test123.service which inside is set to
execute on start/stop the service  in /etc/init.d/foo.sh with parameters start/stop,and
foo.sh when started/stopped directly starts/stops the service
The problem I face is, now I want to upgrade to systemd from init.d and when 
foo.sh is active ,the systemd script shows to be inactive via the command
"systemctl status test123.service" .Is this behaviour expected or something can be changed
in order systemd to see foo.sh status ?

Comment: You've hand-duplicated a procedure that systemd already does for you.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132

Comment: I believe systemd has kind of sys V init compatibility, so I don't think that's a good idea of writing a new service but not deleting original initscript service.Maybe just don't do anything (forget about systemd service file and take advantage of compatibility). Or RTFD and write a new service that call the actual service program and delete foo.sh.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking before starting the systemd ,just to stop and delete the init.d and then cleanly start using systemd?

Answer (score 0):

The .service file and the init script must have the same name, is the initscript is called `/etc/init.d/foo` the service file must be called `foo.service`