# service status return string

Tags: ubuntu, services, nginx

When checking status of a service running on Linux (Ubuntu) machine, I am used to the following output:

```
service status nginx
* nginx is running
```

After recent nginx upgrade, the output of the same command changed to:

```
nginx start/running, process XXXX
```

where `XXXX` is the process number.

I have never seen such format for `service status` response and I'd like to know whether that's normal? Is that another standard or maybe it means that the service wasn't installed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There is no standard.

Whatever comes out depends from your particular implementation of the `service` command *and* what service manager you are using *and even* what service definitions are supplied for the service in question.

### systemd

If you are running systemd as a service manager, the output will be the output of systemd's `systemctl status`, which is what the (new Debian/Ubuntu-supplied) `service` command invokes under the covers:

```
% systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-08-12 20:16:25 CEST; 23s ago
  Process: 24221 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17425 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
%
```

This will be the case on systemd operating systems (that have not been switched to something else), such as Ubuntu 15 and later and Debian 8 and later.

A minor variant is that sometimes there is not a true systemd service unit file, in which case systemd invents one (that wraps a van Smoorenburg `rc` file), and the `Loaded:` line will appear slightly differently (because systemd's generator for such units hides the name of the wrapper unit file in favour of the wrapped van Smoorenburg `rc` file name).

You are clearly using not using a systemd operating system, and the new Debian/Ubuntu `service` command.

#### Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemctl`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132

### nosh

If you are using the nosh toolset, the output will be the output of `system-control status`, which is what the nosh toolset's `service` command invokes under the covers:

```
% service appcafe-nginx status
/var/sv/appcafe-nginx: 
    State   : running since 2019-01-12 17:58:09 +0000; 16h 33m 42s ago
    Main PID: 980
     Started: exit 0 at 2019-01-12 17:58:06 +0000; 16h 33m 45s ago
         Ran: exit 0 at 2019-01-12 17:58:09 +0000; 16h 33m 42s ago
    Config  : enabled
%
```

#### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`service`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/service.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`system-control`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/system-control.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

### Upstart

If you are running Upstart as a service manager, the output will be the output of Upstart's `initctl status` command, which is what the (Debian/Ubuntu-supplied, *old*) `service` command invokes under the covers, as you saw:

```
% initctl status nginx
nginx start/running, process 2543
%
```

This will be the case on Upstart operating systems, such as Ubuntu 6 to Ubuntu 14 and Fedora 9 to Fedora 14.

A wrinkle is that on Ubuntu if there is no Upstart job definition for the service, the (old Debian/Ubuntu-supplied) `service` command falls back from invoking `initctl status` to behaving as the van Smoorenburg toolset behaves.

That is what was happening on your system until you upgraded the nginx package to a newer one that now included an Upstart job definition for nginx.  Before, the fallback was being invoked; now, it is not.  [The Upstart job file](https://sources.debian.org/src/nginx/1.10.1-1/debian/nginx-common.nginx.upstart/) was added in nginx version 1.9.

#### Further reading

- Scott James Remnant (2009).  [`status`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man9/status.9.html).  Upstart user manual.  Ubuntu.
- "[`initctl status`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#initctl-status)". *upstart Cookbook*. Ubuntu.
- Cameron Norman (2014-04-22). *[nginx Upstart job](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745483)*.  Debian Bug #745483.

### OpenRC

If you are using OpenRC, the output will be the output of OpenRC's `rc-service status`, which is what `service` is simply an alias for:

```
% rc-service nginx status
 * status: started
%
```

#### Further reading

- Roy Marples (2009-05-01). [`rc-service`](https://mankier.com/8/rc-service). OpenRC.

### van Smoorenburg `rc`

If you are using the van Smoorenburg toolset, the output will be whatever the `rc` script itself prints when given the `status` subcommand.  In most cases, especially from Debian 9 onwards, this will be the output of a common helper command that handles status printing for most `rc` scripts.  But it could be anything, and is dependent entirely from how the script decides to handle the subcommand.

The van Smoorenburg `rc` script shipped in the Debian nginx package uses Debian's `status_of_proc` helper from its `/lib/lsb/init-functions` library of shell script functions:

```
% status_of_proc -p /var/run/nginx.pid /usr/sbin/nginx nginx
* nginx is running
%
```

Ubuntu has not used van Smoorenburg `init`+`rc` since 2006, so any appearance of van Smoorenburg `rc` behaviour with the (Debian/Ubuntu-supplied) `service` command will be down to the aforementioned wrinkle of Upstart.  The (old) `service` command will have failed to detect an Upstart job and will have fallen back to treating things as van Smoorenburg `rc`.  (Note that there is no such fallback with systemd or nosh, and you will *never* see the van Smoorenburg `rc` behaviour on Ubuntu with either of those, which will always behave as for their native services, which everything runs as.)

#### Further reading

- [LSBInitScripts/StatusSupport](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/StatusSupport).  Debian wiki.

Comment: Huge thanks for the detailed and very helpful answer!