# Failed to reenable unit: Unit file hddtemp.service does not exist

Tags: linux-mint, systemd, services

When doing daily updates on my Linux Mint 20 system, I noticed:

```
Reloading systemd
Failed to reenable unit: Unit file hddtemp.service does not exist.
```

that program I might have used in the past, but not now:

```
$ apt-cache policy hddtemp 
hddtemp:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3-beta15-53
  Version table:
     0.3-beta15-53 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

I thought purging residual configuration would help, but there was none to delete (`sudo apt-get purge hddtemp`).

---

I fail to see where this unit file is placed as I don't usually work with systemd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hddtemp.service` unit file is auto-generated by systemd, as the hddtemp package only has a van Smoorenburg `rc` file.
Such auto-generated unit files, and the symbolic links that enable them from `multi-user.target` et al., live in subdirectories of `/run/systemd`.

## Further reading

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/hddtemp
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[Missing system search paths from the `systemd.unit` manual page](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/systemd-documentation-errata.html#MissingUsrLocalLibSystemd)". *Errata for systemd doco*.  Frequently Given Answers.