# SLES15 SP4 | Installation of a rpm package fails when %post scriplet fails with "/usr/lib/1sb/install _initd: No such file or directory"

Tags: rpm, sles, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a `.spec` file to install a rpm. I have the following snippet in post install (%post scriplet)

```
%post -n %{package_name}
# Enable the service at boot time
%if %{?suse_version:1}0
  /usr/lib/lsb/install_initd %{_initrddir}/%{package_name}
%else
  chkconfig --add %{package_name}
%endi
```

During `zypper install package_name` it fails at the post installation phase with the following error:

```
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Z5R29N: line 2: /usr/lib/1sb/install _initd: No such file or directory
warning: %post (package_name.sles15.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
```

I am a novice in .spec files for rpm but this scriplet failed because `/usr/lib/lsb/` directory doesn't exists in SLES 15 SP4

My Questions are:

1. What is this scriplet exactly doing?
2. Where to get this `/lsb/` package from so that I can create this path in SLES 15 SP4? I check that SLES 15 SP4 pre-installed with lsb-xxx package but they are not working here ?
3. Do I need to do case checks here for sles 15 SP4 inside this scriplet? like:

```
%if 0%{?sle_version} == 150400 && 0%{?is_opensuse}
// do somthing
%endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That spec is extremely outdated

> What is this scriplet exactly doing?

What that snippet does is to install scripts to `init.d`, which are used by [`sysv-init`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#SysV-style), to start services at boot

Since SLE 12, SUSE (and most other distros have switched too) has been using [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), rendering `init.d` totally obsolete and warranting a switch to a service

> Where to get this /lsb/ package from so that I can create this path in SLES 15 SP4? I check that SLES 15 SP4 pre-installed with lsb-xxx package but they are not working here ?

You can't, there are only a very limited support for those means of starting and managing services nowadays, one of those is [`systemd-sysv-generator`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/407300), this is a solution, but I'd go for a native `systemd` solution if that's an important piece of software.

But the snippet, as it is, will never work on SLES 15, it will need to be completely rewritten as `chkconfig` will not also not work

> Do I need to do case checks here for sles 15 SP4 inside this scriplet? like:

If you still support `SLE < 12`, and need to keep the older way to do it, yes you can do that

---

What you need to do, if you want to make it native :

- Find what script it is trying to install
- Using that script as a reference, build a [Systemd service unit file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files#what-do-systemd-units-give-you)
- If you have the source, and you can modify it, add it to the source.
  If you don't have a modifiable source, you'll need to patch it in at buildtime.
- Remove that snippet and follow that [guide](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Systemd_packaging_guidelines) (from openSUSE but will work just fine on SLE) to build it into your code

---

> ```
> %if 0%{?sle_version} == 150400 && 0%{?is_opensuse}
> ```

FYI, this is a conditional that will only match openSUSE Leap 15.4, and not SLE 15.4, this is not an issue as Leap and SLE are the same thing but can be surprising

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response. I really appreciate it.