# Fsck script location

Tags: linux

I need to find out what kind of script runs fsck during the boot on CentOS 7?
I know that all scenarios are located in /etc/rc.d directory.
But I haven't any idea about where is this script is located.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I know that all scenarios are located in `/etc/rc.d` directory.

What you know is wrong.

Welcome to CentOS 7.  The world has changed.  In particular, your base of Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 has changed.  You are using a systemd Linux operating system.  A lot of the received wisdom about Linux is not true for such systems.

`fsck` is *not run by any script at all* on systemd Linux operating systems.

The native format for systemd is the *unit*, which can be amongst other things a *service unit* or a *mount unit*. systemd's service management proper operates solely in terms of those, which it reads from one of nine directories where (system-wide) `.service` and `.mount` files can live.    `/etc/systemd/system`, `/run/systemd/system`, `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system`, and `/usr/lib/systemd/system` are four of those directories.

Your `/etc/fstab` database is converted into mount units by a program named `systemd-fstab-generator`. This program is listed in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/` directory and is thus run automatically by systemd early in the bootstrap process at every boot, and again every time that systemd is instructed to re-load its configuration later on.

This program is a *generator*, a type of ancillary utility whose job is to create unit files on the fly, in a tmpfs where three more of those nine directories (which are intended to be used only by generators) are located.  `systemd-fstab-generator` generates `.mount` units that mount the volumes.  These in their turn reference `.service` units that run `fsck`.

Those `fsck` service units don't themselves exist as files in the filesystem (not even in a tmpfs), and are not the products of a generator.  They are *instantiated* by systemd from a *template* service unit file, named `systemd-fsck@.service`, using the device name as the service unit instance name.  The instantiation happens because of the `Requires=` and `After=` references to `systemd-fsck@device.service` from the generated `.mount` units.

This instantiated template is a service that runs a program named `systemd-fsck`, which sets up a client-server connection for displaying progress information and then in its turn runs `fsck`.  `systemd-fsck` is a compiled C program, not an interpreted script.

### Further reading

- ["New Features: System and Services"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/chap-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7.0_Release_Notes-System_and_Services.html).  *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Release Notes*.  Red Hat.
- Stephen Wadeley (2014).  ["8. Managing Services with systemd"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Services_with_systemd.html) *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 System Administrators' Guide*.  Red Hat.
- [*systemd-fstab-generator*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fstab-generator.html). systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [*systemd-fsck@.service*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html). systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [*systemd.mount*](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html). systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204075/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132

Answer (score 0):

If CentOS 7 is still using the SysV setup, under `/etc/rc.d` are all scripts, a fast `grep` should show where it is called. The scripts themselves are linked (under their names, preceded by precedence) in the `/etc/rc/X` directories, untangling that isn't too hard. Understanding the scripts is another kettle of fish altogether...

If it is already using `systemd` (look e.g. [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) for an overview) the configuration files are under `/lib/systemd`, and specific configuration is in `/etc/systemd`. Again, grap trusty `grep(1)` and dig in.

Comment: Using this :`sudo find / -name "fsck"` I found only this two directories: /usr/sbin/fsck and /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/fsck

Comment: @MRX `/usr/sbin/fsck` is the executable. Not a script, a binary. `which fsck` would have told you faster...