# Set systemd service to execute after fstab mount

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm working on a `systemd` `.service` script that is supposed to start *after* a CIFS network location is mounted via `/etc/fstab` to `/mnt/` on boot-up.

The script waits for an OpenVPN dependency script to launch first, but I also want it to wait for mount to complete.

**/etc/systemd/system/my-daemon.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch My Daemon
After=network.target vpn-launch.service
Requires=vpn-launch.service
```

I tried to add `systemd.mount` to the line: `After=network.target vpn-launch.service systemd.mount`, but it didn't give the results I was hoping for.

Comment: Does it work if you add `systemd-remount-fs` to your `After` list?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

> a CIFS network location is mounted via `/etc/fstab` to `/mnt/` on boot-up.

No, it is not.  Get this right, and the rest falls into place naturally.

The mount is handled by a (generated) systemd *mount unit* that will be named something like `mnt-wibble.mount`.  You can see its actual name in the output of the follwoing command:

```bash
systemctl list-units --type=mount
```

You can look at it in detail just like any other unit with:

```bash
systemctl status
```

Very simply, then: you have to order your unit to be started after that mount unit is started.

```ini
After=network.target vpn-launch.service mnt-wibble.mount
```

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236968/5132

Comment: For followers, "wibble" is just a dummy name, like "foobar"

Comment: Isn't it better to use something like `mnt-[disk name].mount` instead of `mnt-wibble.mount` in the answer so that users would not type that exact name?

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  You also need to add the mount unit to the `Requires=` definition.  See answer below.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me. I'm trying: `After=systemd-udevd mnt-usb23.mount` and also `RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/usb23`. But it doesn't work.

Comment: @damn-vegetables feel free to edit the answer for clarity regarding the unit name

Comment: Regardless of the wibblers in the comments, I found this to be a great answer. I came in looking for a quick "systemd wait until.." hack and I left with slightly more knowledge than I bargained for. Bravo.

Comment: To add the after in the automatically-generated systemd mount, use `x-systemd.requires=after-my.service` (see https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/systemd.mount.5.en.html for details). You need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` for these changes to apply.

Answer (score 36):

Although both answers are correct, I want to add my two cents to the discussion, because when I have looked for it I was missing some instructions and examples of how to proceed.

1. Add the filesystem to `/etc/fstab`
2. Type `mount -a` which mounts all filesystems mentioned in fstab
3. Look for the systemd unit that has been generated with:
   `systemctl list-units | grep '/path/to/mount' | awk '{ print $1 }'`
   (should return something that ends with `.mount`)
4. Add the found mount-unit to the `After=` statement in the `*.service` file

Here is an example of starting the `my-daemon` service on boot but after the network is ready, a CIFS share is mounted at `/mnt/cifs`, and the `vpn-launch` service has started:

**/etc/fstab**

```
//servername/sharename /mnt/cifs cifs defaults,some,other,options 0 0
```

Note: You may want to add `nofail` to your fstab options (e.g. when using an external drive). Otherwise, your machine won't boot if the device is not connected. See [ArchWiki's fstab article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab)

**/etc/systemd/system/my-daemon.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch My Daemon
Requires=vpn-launch.service mnt-cifs.mount
After=network.target vpn-launch.service mnt-cifs.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/my-daemon

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Do not forget to enable the service such that it is started on boot: `systemctl enable my-daemon`

Note that this works for other filesystems (NFS, HDDs, etc.) as well.

As already mentioned, both answers are correct and I encourage everybody to read them but for me a couple of examples would have saved me some time.

Update (2019-06-25):

- added a note regarding fstab options to prevent boot lock when using external drives
- added `mnt-cifs.mount` to the `Requires=` list which causes the `my-daemon.service` fail to start-up when the cifs mount was not successfully mounted

Comment: Just to be clear, "mnt-cifs.mount" is the name of the mount unit for your specific mount-point from `systemctl list-units --type=mount`?

Comment: This answer is more complete.  You also need the `Requires=` definition.  Unfortunately even that may not work during boot because systemd has a bug described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/952668/systemd-starting-service-even-if-service-in-requires-wont-start/).  Does anyone know a workaround to the bug?

Answer (score 26):

Sorry but I can't comment yet.

Like JdeBP said, you should be ordering on the filesystem mount. You can predict the name of the mount unit or, alternatively, you can use (in unit section):

> RequiresMountsFor=/absolute/path/of/mount

This option creates the dependencies to the appropriate *.mount units to make the path accessible before starting the service. It may not be on all systemd versions, but I've been using it in a CentOS 7 machine for the last 6 months or so.

Comment: (And [your differences from vanilla systemd are here](https://git.centos.org/tree/rpms!systemd/c7/SOURCES).)  `RequiresMountsFor=` does come with its own set of caveats.  With [RedHat bug #1088057](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1088057) and [Chris Siebenmann](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/SystemdAndBindMounts) in hand, you should be able to answer https://superuser.com/questions/988734/ .  It's a CIFS mount in this question, too.  But the implication is that it is `auto`, fortunately.

Comment: @JdeBP Thank you for the comment. I wasn't aware of the caveats and issues on that feature.

Comment: The issue with `RequiresMountsFor=` was that it didn't pull in the units to do the mount if they were not required by something else.  E.g., `noauto` mounts in fstab.  But this was changed ~2017 so there shouldn't be a problem using `RequiresMountsFor` anymore.

Comment: Simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere: how would I go about requiring multiple mounts? Is it space-delimited like other parameters?

Comment: Seems to be space seoarated as you suspected: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html

Answer (score 2):

First determine the mount unit name with:

```
systemctl list-units --type=mount
```

It will likely be named after the mountpoint in /mnt such as

```
mnt-syncthing\x2ddeb.mount
```

for a mount point of /mnt/syncthing .

Then add this mount unit to the After= directive in your service, such as:

```
After=network.target mnt-syncthing\x2ddeb.mount
```

Edit your service with

```
systemctl edit --full [servicename.service]
```

to preserve the config after an update.  Now your service will wait for the mount before starting!

Comment: As far as I can tell, this doesn’t add any information to what [JdeBP’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/246935/80216#247547) and [bm-bergmotte’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/246935/80216#412070) already say.

Answer (score 0):

@bm-bergmotte: thanks for your instruction which helped me a lot.
For me it´s just working, if I put

```
After=network.target vpn-launch.service mnt-cifs.mount
Requires=vpn-launch.service mnt-cifs.mount
```

If I don´t put "mnt-cifs.mount" inside the "Requires" (and in this order) it works for reboot/ startup, but the service starts anyway, if the device is not mounted. After putting it additionally inside ""Requires" the service mounts the device before starting it, if the device was not mounted.

Comment: You are right. If the mount fails then the my-daemon.service is started anyway. `After=` just dictates the order. `Requires=` makes it mandatory that the cifs mount must be present (see [Sufiyan Ghori answer](https://serverfault.com/a/931383/388473) on that one). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Doesn't `Requires=` _imply_ `After=`, or is `After=` still, um.. required?