# fstab mounting time

Tags: ubuntu, cron, fstab, sysvinit

I'm working on a script that is supposed to execute on startup, but the problem is that the script requires some files that are on a shared drive that is automatically mounted via fstab and at the time of it's execution the drive isn't mounted yet.

I've tried using cron @reboot and init.d route but they both execute too early.  I also considered adding `mount -a` to the script, but I would rather avoid having to `sudo` it. For now I just added a delay to make it work, but that feels a bit hacky.

Is there a way to ensure that a startup script runs after fstab has been processed? Or force the mounts to be processed without using `sudo`?

Comment: You are using Ubuntu, an operating system that has been a systemd operating system since 2016 and was an Upstart operating system for a decade before that, since 2006. van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts have not been a "route" for a long time on your operating system.  The systemd version of this question has already been asked and answered here at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to run your script as a **systemd** unit (assuming you have systemd) where you could define dependency...

If you want to stick with **cron @reboot** (what sounds the simple choice) you have to make your script a bit smarter (or start cron after fs mounts... what change I wouldn't suggest). Instead of a simple delay, you can check if the required filesystem is mounted (in bash):

```
while ! mount | awk '{print $3}' | grep -qx /the/mountpoint; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Or you can check if the file is there what you need:

```
while ! [ -f /that/file ] ; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're on a relatively new Linux distro, so you may need to check `systemd` manual since `SysV` is no longer being used in the default distro installations and that is most probably your problem. `systemd` allows for startup dependencies where you specify what scripts run before others.

Check the next [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/617823/how-to-set-systemd-service-dependencies#617839)