# Failed to start systemd service during boot

Tags: systemd, mount, fstab

I'm trying to start the systemd service during boot once fstab entries mounted.

I have followed [Set systemd service to execute after fstab mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount/570837#570837) and added below details

```
# cat /etc/fstab
/dev/mmcblk1p11 /data       ext4    defaults        0 2

# systemctl list-units | grep '/data' | awk '{ print $1 }'
data.mount

# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/data.service
[Unit]
Description=My system
After=data.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=mountpoint -q /data
ExecStart=/usr/etc/data.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Problem is, it won't start during boot. However, the manual restart seems working.

```
# systemctl status data.service
  data.service - My system
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/data.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

# systemctl enable data.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/data.service ��→ /usr/lib/systemd/system/data.service.
# systemctl restart data.service
         Starting My system...
[  OK  ] Started My system.
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would try. 
You stated manual startup worked but in your example you show

```
systemctl enable data.service
```

Did you do this enable command before you restarted? It has to be enabled to start on boot.

2nd I think the After= line needs to be the service name. 
Try to change

```
After=data.mount
```

to

```
After=data.service
```

and see what happens.