# How to set supervisord to start after the /etc/fstab mount

Tags: linux, supervisord

I am using supervisord to control and monitor my application. My application uses the mount configured in /etc/fstab and the application needs to start after entries in /etc/fstab are mounted during every restart of the machine. But in rare cases, my application starts before the /etc/fstab entries are mounted and picks up the unmounted directory.

I am looking for options for supervisord / solution as in the below thread.

[Set systemd service to execute after fstab mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount)

Do we have any option in supervisord which is similar to 'After=' option which available in systemd ?

Answer (score -1):

You can put the dependency on local-fs.target. Hope this will solve the problem. Otherwise, you can put dependency on all the required .mount.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).