# inittab respawn and rc.local

Tags: bash, init-script, daemon, init

At the moment I have a daemon starting at boot using `rc.local` by the following line.

```
su -l user -c '/dir/daemon'
```

but I would like to start this process as a service with respawn. I found out that it should be added to `/etc/inittab` with something like

```
daemon:run-level:respawn:script-to-daemon
```

1. which run level should I use?
2. how do I have it executed as `user`?
3. if I'm using `inittab` should I remove the line in `rc.local`
4. is there something like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) that'll do this for me

Answer (score 1):

## Forget about `/etc/inittab`.

If you have Ubuntu with upstart, or one of the systemd operating systems, then your system completely ignores `/etc/inittab` and it is a complete irrelevance.

- Scott James Remnant and James Hunt.  [`inittab`(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/inittab.5.html).  Ubuntu version 12 manual pages.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196197/5132

## Forget about runlevels.

They exist in systemd operating systems, but only as compatibility shims. The systemd documentation states that the concept is "obsolete". If you're starting with this on a systemd operating system, don't start there.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132

## Forget about `forever`.

If you have a service manager, be it runit, systemd, perp, nosh, upstart, s6, or daemontools-encore, then *it's already doing* what you think you need `forever` for.

- https://askubuntu.com/a/625378/43344

## Take your stuff out of `rc.local`.

On an upstart or systemd system it's really as much of a compatibility shim as runlevels are.

## Put your stuff into an upstart job or a systemd service unit.

The latter would look something like

```
[Unit]
Description=Start the wibble daemon

[Service]
User=wibble-d
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/wibbled
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- https://askubuntu.com/a/613785/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/623085/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/626858/43344

Comment: Thanks, but systemd or upstart is not an option, the system in question is running lenny, and updating is a huge pain (its a vortex86 processor and the manufacturer provided patched kernel recommends debian 5) instead of going in to a partial upgrade, I'd rather figure out how to use inittab.