# chkconfig equivalent - RHEL7

Tags: rhel, systemd, chkconfig

In the good old days you would use `chkconfig` to see if a service was enabled for a run level. E.g.

```
chkconfig --list tgtd
```

However, now you're supposed to use `systemctl`. But I can't get `systemctl` to give a similarly succinct output as `chkconfig`.

Any suggestions on how you do so?

Comment: Not the exactly answer. I use `insserv -s | grep whatever`

Comment: check here for a bit more details about Systemd : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158872/does-systemd-still-know-about-runlevels

Answer (score 2):

You can check if it is enabled or disables by using this command:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

Where "`--type=service`" helps you narrow it down to services only.

And you can enable/disable services with commands:

```
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl disable httpd
```

Comment: Yes. So `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | grep tgtd` which gives
`tgtd.service                                enabled`. Not quite as succinct but does the job.

Comment: `list-unit-files` takes a pattern.  There is no need for `grep`.