# Why does `init 0` result in "Excess Arguments" on Arch install?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, init, runlevel

I am used to the old method of calling `init 0` to shutdown. Bad, I know; but when I tried it on my new Arch install I get this:

```
# init 0
Excess Arguments
```

This confuses me because I thought `systemd` was supposed to support run levels? Looking at the man page, it mentions this:

> For compatibility with SysV, if systemd is called as init and a PID
>   that is not 1, it will execute telinit and pass all command line
>   arguments unmodified. That means init and telinit are mostly
>   equivalent when invoked from normal login sessions. See telinit(8) for
>   more information.

Am I just using the wrong syntax or have I completely misunderstood `systemd`?

### More Init/Systemd Information

```
# command -v init
/usr/bin/init

# file /bin/init
/usr/bin/init: symbolic link to ../lib/systemd/systemd

# /lib/systemd/systemd --version
systemd 234
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

```
# command -v telinit
/usr/bin/telinit

# file /bin/telinit
/bin/telinit: symbolic link to systemctl

# systemctl --version
systemd 234
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

### General System Info

```
# uname -a
Linux arch 4.12.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 11 12:40:21 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Note that `telinit 0` (linked to systemctl) _will_ continue to work regardless of build options; only `init 0` (linked to systemd) does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For compatibility with SysV, […]

```
systemd 234
[…] -SYSVINIT […]
```

You've built systemd without the compatibility option, so the compatibility behaviour described in the manual is not going to be present.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as I can see from your symlinks this is the issue.

If your `init` is a symlink to `systemd` then you need to see what systemd can get as an argument.

```
systemd [OPTIONS...]

Starts up and maintains the system or user services.

  -h --help                      Show this help
     --test                      Determine startup sequence, dump it and exit
     --no-pager                  Do not pipe output into a pager
     --dump-configuration-items  Dump understood unit configuration items
     --unit=UNIT                 Set default unit
     --system                    Run a system instance, even if PID != 1
     --user                      Run a user instance
     --dump-core[=BOOL]          Dump core on crash
     --crash-vt=NR               Change to specified VT on crash
     --crash-reboot[=BOOL]       Reboot on crash
     --crash-shell[=BOOL]        Run shell on crash
     --confirm-spawn[=BOOL]      Ask for confirmation when spawning     processes
     --show-status[=BOOL]        Show status updates on the console during bootup
     --log-target=TARGET         Set log target (console, journal, kmsg, journal-or-kmsg, null)
     --log-level=LEVEL           Set log level (debug, info, notice, warning, err, crit, alert, emerg)
     --log-color[=BOOL]          Highlight important log messages
     --log-location[=BOOL]       Include code location in log messages
     --default-standard-output=  Set default standard output for services
     --default-standard-error=   Set default standard error output for services
```

So the thing is that you actually don't have the real `init` but just a linked `systemd`

Comment: Thank you for the info! I get why it errors, but I don't get it doesn't pass to a real `init` since the man page says that it will execute `telinit` with all arguments passed unmodified?

Comment: well a deeper look on your systems is the answer :) systemd can't do what you expect if you don't enable the `-SYSVINIT` flag on the compilation :) hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra package "systemd-sysvcompat", and after that you can `sysvinit 0` (and maybe telinit) - but then you need this inittab again, and the halt/shutdown/reboot of Slackware 14.2 (no systemd there) did not convince me.

This **/usr/bin/sysvinit** has the same size as the "old" init, and inside it reads: `GCC: (GNU) 4.9.2`, and `miquels@cistron.nl` (I know that name! he wrote sysvinit!). So this IS sysv-init. They just had to rename it. In the package it is called /usr/bin/init.

Alas, poor Init! getting pushed around like that!

---

```
re:6:once:/sbin/reboot
```

This is from my inittab I use when I boot with `init=/usr/bin/sysvinit`. /sbin/reboot is a link to...systemctl! Well it works, but I am not saying go ahead...(not my invention, I found it like that installed by archlinux)