# Restart mosquitto - Unknown operation mosquitto

Tags: arch-linux, mqtt

I am running the mosquitto broker on arch linux x64.
I wanted to restart the mosquitto service by doing the following:

```
sudo systemctl mosquitto restart
```

But apparently I am prompted with

```
Unknown operation mosquitto.
```

How can I restart the mosquitto service correctly?

Comment: Arch's init system is systemd.

Comment: @jasonwryan sorry for being unclear. I updated my question. I tried to use `systemctl` to restart the service but I am promted with `Unknown operation mosquitto`

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Using_units

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) expects the command (`start`, `restart`, `status` etc.) *before* the unit (or units):

```
sudo systemctl restart mosquitto
```

You incorrectly used the same syntax for `systemctl` that you were using for `service` in the previous version of your question:

```
sudo service mosquitto restart
```

The reason that *that* did not work is that Arch Linux defaults to providing somewhat fewer compatibility and migration measures than other systemd operating systems.  Debian Linux and Fedora, for example, come with a `service` command, compatible with the command of that name that they have had long before systemd, that invokes `systemctl`.  You don't get such a command out of the box with Arch Linux, nor some of the "compat" parts of systemd itself (c.f. "[Why does `init 0` result in "Excess Arguments" on Arch install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389289/)").