# initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart

Tags: upstart

I recently upgraded my server from Ubuntu V14.04 to V16.04 and now systemctl doesn't seem to work anymore.

I need to prevent transmission-daemon from starting automatically on boot so I issue the command

```
sudo systemctl disable transmission-daemon.service
```

And I get the following response

```
Synchronizing state of transmission-daemon.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable transmission-daemon
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `transmission-daemon' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `transmission-daemon' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

The service does not become disabled

---

**Update**
Per @JdeBP deleting the screen-cleanup script resolved the problem

```
$ sudo rm /etc/init.d/screen-cleanup
$ sudo systemctl disable transmission-daemon.service

Synchronizing state of transmission-daemon.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable transmission-daemon
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `transmission-daemon' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `transmission-daemon' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `transmission-daemon' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 2 3 4 5 6) of script `transmission-daemon' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
```

I can see the service is now **disabled** as required

```
systemctl status transmission-daemon
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; disabled; ve
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service.d
           └─local.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-03-08 08:16:00 EST; 2 days ago
 Main PID: 2423 (transmission-da)
   Status: "Uploading 329.89 KBps, Downloading 11.04 KBps."
   CGroup: /system.slice/transmission-daemon.service
           └─2423 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error -g /etc/transmissi
```

Comment: Answers belong in answers, not in questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install` is a hook whose job is to do the non-native enable/disable actions that `systemd-sysv-generator` and other service management systems will recognize.  Ubuntu's `/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install` simply calls Ubuntu's `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d`.  That in turn calls `/sbin/insserv`.  That in turn sees that there's a van Smoorenbug `rc` script in `/etc/init.d` and tries to get LSB header information from it.

`/sbin/insserv` has a special case where it recognizes when the van Smoorenburg `rc` script that it has found is really a symbolic link to Upstart's `/lib/init/upstart-job` program.  Because that's a generic program that fills in for many van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts, it won't have LSB header information appropriate to specific services.  So `/sbin/insserv` tries to invoke the `rc` script, really `/lib/init/upstart-job`, with the `lsb-header` subcommand to get it to calculate and print out the right LSB headers for the service.

But `/lib/init/upstart-job` does not in fact support that subcommand.  The softwares were never integrated properly.  `/lib/init/upstart-job` runs `initctl`, which tries to connect to a running Upstart service manger and of course fails (because one is not running) and prints the first error that you see about not being able to connect to socket `/com/ubuntu/upstart`, and then it prints the second error that you see about the `lsb-header` subcommand not being supported "for Upstart jobs" (even though *those were what it was for*).

The upshot is that it all goes wrong.

It has been going wrong for years.  One can find people reporting this bug, which of course happened when people ran `insserv` directly or indirectly under Upstart and van Smoorenburg `init` too, going back well over a decade at this point.  [It was asked about on AskUbuntu in 2016.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776524/)  It is several Launchpad bugs such as [this one from 2016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binfmt-support/+bug/1610620).

Interestingly, in one of those Launchpad bugs, one from 2010, [someone attempted to supply a patch so that `upstart-job` would understand the `lsb-header` subcommand](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/insserv/+bug/467000/comments/5) and give `insserv` at least *something* to work with, even if it was fairly uninformative.  Nobody, except some users who did not have the access to fix the software themselves, noticed.

Of course, these van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts are wrappers around Upstart for the benefit of softwares and people that do not understand how to drive Upstart directly with `initctl`, but do know how to drive the old van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts.  However, you are using Ubuntu 16; a systemd operating system.  systemd's backwards compatibility mechanism is taking some van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts that *themselves* are *something else's* backwards compatibility mechanism, wrapping them up in systemd native units, and ending up trying to reflect commands sent to a systemd service manager to an Upstart service manager that isn't there.

This is just ludicrous.

1. Find the symbolic link in `/etc/init.d` that is pointing to `/lib/init/upstart-job`.  By the looks of things it is `/etc/init.d/screen-cleanup`.
2. Remove it.

The icing on the cake is that `transmission-daemon` is controlled by a native systemd service unit (`/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service`) on Ubuntu 16, and van Smoorenburg `rc` backwards compatibility mechanisms and `/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install` do not apply to it in the first place.

## Further reading

- Petter Reinholdtsen (2009-09-17). *[insserv: Should handle /lib/init/upstart-job entries](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=547235#5)*.  Debian bug #547235.
- "[UPSTART JOB COMPATIBILITY](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/insserv/insserv.8.en.html#UPSTART_JOB_COMPATIBILITY)".  `insserv`.  Debian 7 manual pages.
- https://sources.debian.org/src/upstart/1.11-5/debian/upstart-job/#L114
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394191/5132

Comment: Very detailed. Might want to draw the reader's eyes to the solution at the bottom and leave the history lesson to those that want more depth. Great answer though!