# /etc/init.d and /etc/rcX.d/: how do they work with systemd

Tags: systemd, sysvinit, rc

I've known that Debian and Ubuntu have used `systemd` to manage the services running at boot time.

I've known that there were `/etc/rcX.d/` and `/etc/init.d/`, which are also about services running at boot time.

Now I want to know how do `/etc/rcX.d/`, `/etc/init.d/` and `systemd` work together.

After reading
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd-sysv-generator.8.en.html
and
[How does systemd use /etc/init.d scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/how-does-systemd-use-etc-init-d-scripts)
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901385/whats-the-exactly-differences-of-etc-init-d-something-and-etc-rc-local

I'm confused now.

It seems that `systemd` will transform the scripts in `/etc/rcX.d` and in `/etc/init.d` into the service that can be read by `systemd`. But what is the rule of the transformation? The first link and the second link told me that `systemd` would transform the script in `/etc/init.d` into the service, which is `after basic.target`, and the script in `/etc/rcX.d` into the service, which is `Wanted-By multi-user.target`. But the third link told me that `/etc/rcX.d/` contains many soft links to the scripts located in `/etc/init.d/`. Doesn't this make any conflict?

For me, it seems that adding script in `/etc/init.d`and in `/etc/rcX.d` is the same because adding script in both of them can be execute at boot time.

Comment: I _did not_ tell you that `/etc/rc?.d` contains scripts.  I explicitly wrote "symbolic link farms".

Comment: It says "symbolic link farms" at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394191/5132 too.

Comment: @JdeBP  thanks a lot dude, let me read it again.