# Understanding shutdown command in inittab

Tags: shutdown, init

Looking in my /etc/inittab file I see the following entry:

```
ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now
```

What do the -t1 and -a options mean? They do not appear in the manual for the shutdown command. I have also seen another /etc/inittab in a reference book that shows:

```
ca::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -r -t 4 now
```

Since no runlevel is specified, does this mean that it is works for all run levels from 0 to 6? What does the "-t 4" mean?

Also, is there a reason why the -a and -t options are not mentioned in the manual for the shutdown command?

Comment: As noted in one of the answers you are probably, given what you say, using an operating system where [`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html), so what it contains is entirely irrelevant to the actual operation of your machine.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132 and what it hyperlinks to for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those options are options to the `sysvinit` version of `shutdown` (see [the relevant manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/sysvinit-core/shutdown.8)):

> `-t sec`
>
> Tell `init(8)` to wait *sec* seconds between sending processes the warning and the kill signal, before changing to another runlevel.
>
> `-a`
>
> Use `/etc/shutdown.allow`.

This version of `-t` is also valid in your second example, which as you guess applies to any runlevel.

The options are no longer mentioned in your version of the manual because that’s no doubt [the systemd version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/shutdown.8.html), which doesn’t support them.

Comment: … and which totally ignores `/etc/inittab` in any case.  [Upstart's `shutdown` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/shutdown.8.html) does not mention these, either. Upstart does not use `/etc/inittab` either and unlike systemd has [a manual page saying that](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/inittab.5.html)