# Are runlevels 0 and 6 a result or a transition?

Tags: linux, boot, shutdown, reboot, runlevel

The runlevels 0 and 6 have the meaning of shutting down or rebooting the system.

If I enter the command `init 0`, the system will shut down as a result.

However my question is

1. if the system is shutting down, *because* it has successfuly changed to runlevel 0
2. or if I only triggered the change from my current runlevel to runlevel 0
   (i.e. told my system that I want to go to runlevel 0) and it will reach it *after* shutdown? 
   Which is of course *never*, as the system will do nothing after powered down.

In other words: Is the system in runlevel 0

- ***while*** the system is shutting down (during the transition from running to being shut down), or
- ***after*** the system has been shut down (as an unreachable runlevel that describes the result) ?

And an additional question regarding runlevel 6: Is the system in runlevel 6 during any phase of the next boot?

I am interested in the behaviour of Linux (if there is any difference to Unix).

Comment: [Forget about runlevels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132).

Answer (score 1):

`init` (whether you're using a classic SVR4 style `init`, systemd, runit, or something else) is coded as a state-machine.  It only does things in response to events that cause it to change states.  The transition from a system being powered on to being powered off is a change from whatever the current state is to the state defined by runlevel 0, and the shutdown for a reboot is the same, just changing to the state defined by runlevel 6 (and actually, the both transitions are pretty much identical except for that one final call into the kernel by `init`).

To answer your second question, the system is functionally 'in runlevel 6' during the period of time from when `init` calls into the kernel to reboot (which does not return) until the kernel hands off execution to `init during the next boot.

Comment: The implication of the _whether you're using … systemd_ is that these systems have run levels too   They do not.  [systemd does not have runlevels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132).  Neither does `runit-init`, which maps just the numbers 0 and 6 onto native mechanisms; nor `runsvchdir` which manipulates named collections of service directory links.  In fact, _nothing_ apart from van Smoorenburg `init` and  Nikola Vladov's `ninit` _actually has_ runlevels.

Comment: @JdeBP No, systemd does support the concept of runlevels,it just doesn't call them runlevels, it calls them 'targets'.  Functionally, they are identical, even though the naming is different.