# Change runlevel with systemd

Tags: systemd, runlevel

`systemd` still maintains the general idea of runlevels with its "Targets", but how do I change the system runlevel through `systemd`?

I want to do something equivalent to the old `init`-script method of:

```
init 3 # Multi-user
init 5 # Graphical
```

Comment: That's because you are looking for something that in the systemd world is obsolete.  [Forget about runlevels](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/run-levels-are-history.html), as I said in an answer to that very question.

Comment: Questions in other Answers are exactly what "Duplicates" are for.

Comment: Yes, the answer for [that Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158872/13308) would have answered this Question, but the Question itself was different.

Answer (score 9):

[From freedesktop.org's own systemd FAQ](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/), to change the (running) Target (system runlevel), use `systemctl isolate TARGET.target`:

```
systemctl isolate multi-user.target # or runlevel3.target
systemctl isolate graphical.target # or runlevel5.target
```

To change the default Target (default system runlevel, for the next reboot), use `systemctl set-default TARGET`:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```