# runlevel + what is runlevel 5 3 in redhat linux

Tags: rhel, runlevel, multiuser

we know that `runlevl` of multi user mode is

```
N 5
```

but on our redhat 7.2 we get the following

```
runlevel

5 3
```

what is the meaning of this run-level ?

how to change this machine to multi user mode ( full permissions )

and when we do

```
who -r
```

we get

```
run-level 3                last=5
```

Note - we perform `reboot/init 6` , but still we are in `run-level 3`

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/158872/117549

Comment: Redhat Linux 7.2 or RHEL 7.2?  What is the output of “uname-r”

Comment: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64

Comment: Are you intentionally running a 4+ year old OS with no security fixes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the meaning of this run-level ?

It means that word has still not percolated everywhere, even after it being explicitly stated in the systemd manual for its `runlevel` command since 2010, that *this concept is obsolete*.

Forget about run levels.

Your operating system does not have run levels.  As explained at length in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132 , they simply do not exist outwith a few compatibility shims.  What you see from the systemd `runlevel` command is a fiction, constructed from the states of the *actual* systemd mechanisms, by its almost wholly undocumented `systemd-update-utmp` program.

(I took a slightly different approach in the nosh toolset.  I documented the `login-update-utmpx` command.  But it makes no effort to construct fictions and I also made the `runlevel` shim just print "N N" to drive home the point that *there are no run levels*.  Upstart's choice of printing "unknown" turns out to break some badly written package installation/deinstallation scripts.)

Run levels have been obsolete since 1990, and your operating system finally caught up with that 10 years ago, in RedHat Enterprise Linux version 6 when it switched to Upstart (which also did not operate in terms of run levels, but provided a slightly more extensive compatibility shim than systemd does).  It has been more than 5 years since version 7 where it switched from Upstart to a system whose manual pages explicitly documented this as obsolete.

Ironically, systemd's `runlevel` *is not even telling you* that your system has *not* come up in multi-user mode.  So it is pointless and ill-founded to ask how to switch to multi-user mode, considering that `multi-user.target` is probably already active on your system.  To determine *that* of course, you use `systemctl status multi-user.target`, and *not* the `runlevel` command at all.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [*run-levels are things of the past.*](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/run-levels-are-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Zbigniew Jędrzejewski-Szmek (2015-11-08). *[man: describe the reason why runlevels are obsolete.  Put it at the top of the file, where it's hard to miss.](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/9f6434a675a1b855c8e7d59195a7f066b9022021)*.  systemd. github.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. *[`login-update-utmpx`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/login-update-utmpx.xml)*.  nosh Guide.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. *[`runlevel`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/runlevel.xml)*.  nosh Guide.  Softwares.