# How to boot into single user mode in Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux, permissions, boot

I am using Linux Mint on my office laptop and there are two user accounts on it. one is the director's account and the other is mine. Although I did 
`sudo` command on the terminal before now I cant.It shows below error

```
chathurika@sanjayak-HP-Notebook ~ $ sudo su
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

To fix the permissions of sudo one told to Boot into single-user mode and do `chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo`. I am new to these things. How to do that. Below I have mentioned OS released details

- NAME="Linux Mint"
- VERSION="18 (Sarah)"
- ID=linuxmint
- ID_LIKE=ubuntu
- PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18"
- VERSION_ID="18"
- HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
- SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
- BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
- UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial

Answer (score 2):

> Boot into single-user mode

It has not been single-user mode since 1995.  You have *emergency mode* and *rescue mode*.  Either will do for your purposes, as presumably `chmod` and `sudo` are on the root filesystem.  (In the unlikely event that `/usr` is on a separate filesystem, pick rescue mode.  Also pick rescue mode if in emergency mode you find that your `/` filesystem is mounted read-only.)

When the GRUB menu shows, select a "rescue mode" option if you have one.  If you do not have one, use <kbd>e</kbd> to edit your normal bootstrap selection and add in a `-s` or a `-b` to the kernel command line, for rescue mode and emergency mode respectively.  <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> boots with the edited command line, of course.

- Do not use `systemctl set-default` as that makes a permanent change to how your operating system starts.  You want a one-time modification, so that you can go back to bootstrapping normally thereafter with no further effort.
- Forget about run-levels.  Do not start learning about them.  systemd does not have them in reality.  Learn the paradigms that your operating system actually has.
- You can use other kernel command line options such as `emergency`, `1`, `systemd.unit=emergency`, `single`, `S`, and so forth.  `-s` and `-b` are the most widely accepted across many system management toolsets, not just systemd, and are the original options from 1995.
- Be aware that *whatever you did* to mess up `sudo` has probably caused further problems on your system.

Mint might provide you with a "recovery mode" GRUB menu choice.  You can use this, too.  It isn't any of systemd's bootstrap targets, though.  (It runs a program named `/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu` via an additional systemd target set up by [the friendly-recovery package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/friendly-recovery).)  "recovery mode" in Ubuntu and derivatives is not *rescue mode*.

## Further reading

- `man systemd.special`
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[The gen on emergency and rescue mode bootstrap](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/emergency-and-rescue-mode-bootstrap.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394238/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559867/5132

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 18 uses `systemd` as its init system. That said, you can issue a command that changes the default runlevel to single-user, somewhere this is called 'rescue' mode and it's numerically equal to 1. The command is:

```
systemctl set-default rescue.target
```

You can also issue this without the '.target' part.

Check other runlevels also:

```
   ┌─────────┬───────────────────┐
   │Runlevel │ Target            │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │0        │ poweroff.target   │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │1        │ rescue.target     │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │2, 3, 4  │ multi-user.target │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │5        │ graphical.target  │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │6        │ reboot.target     │
   └─────────┴───────────────────┘
```